# Problema al utilizar un while loop

Tags: c++, while

Cordial saludo, debo realizar un programa que cumpla los siguientes requerimientos:

Es necesario llevar un control de la cantidad total de productos vendidos y los ingresos netos diarios generados en cada una de sus categorías, para ello se debe de solicitar la cantidad de productos vendidos durante el día, posteriormente se debe registrar el nombre del producto, la  ID del producto y la categoría del mismo, teniendo en cuenta que existen 3 categorías y que hay un rango de precios asociados a cada una de ellas:
Los precios de los productos de cada categoría deben de estar en los siguientes rangos:

- Categoría A: 20.000 y 80.000
- Categoría B: 8.000 y 50.000
- Categoría C: 100.000 y 200.000

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main (){
  cout << "\t\tEjercicio 4\n";

  int cantidad_vendida = 0;
  string nombre_producto;
  vector<string> nombres;

  int id_producto;
  vector<int> id;

  char categoria_producto;
  vector<char> categoria;

  //Obtencion de la cantidad de productos vendidos
  cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de productos vendidos en el dia: ";
  cin >> cantidad_vendida;

  //Obtencion de la informacion
  cout << "Los productos pertenecen a tres categorias:\n";
  cout << "Categoria A: 20.000 y 80.000\n";
  cout << "Categoria B: 8.000 y 50.000\n";
  cout << "Categoria C: 100.000 y 200.000\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_vendida; i++) {
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> nombre_producto;
    nombres.push_back(nombre_producto);

    cout << "Ingrese el id del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> id_producto;
    id.push_back(id_producto);
    bool verificacion = false;
    while(verificacion == false){
      cout << "Ingrese la categoria del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
      categoria_producto = getchar();
      if ((categoria_producto == 'A')||(categoria_producto == 'B')||(categoria_producto == 'C')) {
        cout << "La opcion ingresada es: " << categoria_producto;
        verificacion = true;
      } else {
        cout << "Ingrese una categoria correcta.";
      }
    }
    categoria.push_back(categoria_producto);
  }

  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al realizar la comprobación de la categoría ingresada por el usuario, el `while loop` se ejecuta una vez sin que el usuario haya ingresado valor alguno por lo que intenté trabajar con `cin.getline()` y `getchar()` pero ninguno ha corregido el error.
Tal vez sea mejor utilizar un `do-while` en lugar de un `while`? Aunque creo que sería lo mismo... Alguna sugerencia, por favor?

PD: Los vectores son sólo para almacenar los valores ingresados por el usuario ya que al terminar de ingresar dichos valores, debo imprimir en pantalla todo lo guardado.

Gracias de antemano.

Edito:

Ahora tengo el inconveniente que al imprimir el valor, no me está imprimiendo lo que deseo.
Contexto: Vivo en Colombia y aquí se maneja el peso como moneda oficial.
Por ejemplo, 1 dólar equivale a 3.000 pesos (léase como "tres mil pesos").
Por este motivo, el usuario va a ingresar el precio del producto de la siguiente manera:
3.000
Pero al imprimir, el programa muestra lo siguiente: 3

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que imprima en el formato que le dí?

Lo que intenté: 
1. Multiplicar el precio x 1.0. NO FUNCIONÓ
2. Utilizar typecasting a pesar de que el tipo de variable es float. NO FUNCIONÓ
3. Utilizar una coma (,) en lugar de punto pero el programa sigue imprimiendo sólo 3.
4. Utilizar setprecision(2) pero esto agrega decimales y no es lo que deseo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Código actualizado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main (){
cout << "\t\tEjercicio 4\n";

int cantidad_vendida = 0;
string nombre_producto;
vector<string> nombres;

string id_producto;
vector <string> id;

char categoria_producto;
vector <char> categoria;

float valor_producto = 0;
vector <float> valor;

//Obtencion de la cantidad de productos vendidos
cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de productos vendidos en el dia: ";
cin >> cantidad_vendida;

//Obtencion de la informacion
cout << "Los productos pertenecen a tres categorias:\n";
cout << "Categoria A: 20.000 y 80.000\n";
cout << "Categoria B: 8.000 y 50.000\n";
cout << "Categoria C: 100.000 y 200.000\n";

for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_vendida; i++) {
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Ingrese el nombre del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> nombre_producto;
  nombres.push_back(nombre_producto);

  cout << "Ingrese el id del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> id_producto;
  cin.ignore();
  id.push_back(id_producto);

  bool verificacion = false;
  while(verificacion == false){
    cout << "Ingrese la categoria del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
    categoria_producto = getchar();
    cin.ignore();
    if ((categoria_producto == 'A')||(categoria_producto == 'B')||(categoria_producto == 'C')) {
      verificacion = true;
    } else {
      cout << "No ha ingresado una categoria correcta.\n";
    }
  }
  categoria.push_back(categoria_producto);

  //Obtiene el valor del producto
  cout << "Ingrese el valor del producto " << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> valor_producto;
  cin.ignore();
  valor.push_back(valor_producto);
  cout << endl;

}

cout << endl << endl;
cout << "Impresion de los articulos" << endl << endl;

cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_vendida; i++) {
  cout << "Nombre del articulo " << i+1 << ": " << nombres[i] << endl;
  cout << "Id del articulo " << i+1 << ": " << id[i] << endl;
  cout << "Categoria del articulo " << i+1 << ": " << categoria[i] << endl;

  cout << "Valor del articulo " << i+1 << ": " << valor[i] << endl;
  cout << endl;
}

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Pantallazo de lo que ingresa el usuario y lo que imprime el programa]

Comment: pon un cin.ignore(); despues del cin >> id_producto; eso debería solucionarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias! Sí funcionó, aunque ahora tengo otro inconveniente al imprimir un valor. Te agradecería si pudieras echar un vistazo a la edición que hice en la pregunta. Muchas gracias!